# Shortcut to navigate windows explorer to change current working directory?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, script, shortcuts, navigation

I am looking for a way to navigate quickly in Window Explorer, say using a custom right click menu option, between two folder of the same name, but in a different directory structure location. For example if I have currently navigated to this folder:

C:\Drafts\Projects\Project A

I would like to switch to this alternate location without using manual navigation:

C:\Final\Projects\Project A

Both the C:\Drafts\Projects\ and the C:\Final\Projects\ locations have the same child directory structure (i.e. will have identical subfolders named Project A, Project B, Project C).

Basically I am looking for a way to come up with a shortcut to navigate 2 folders up, switch to the "Final" folder, then switch to "Project A". I would like to do this for any Project folder that I am currently in.

I would also like to do the reverse (switch from the "Final" folder, to the "Drafts" folder of the specific Project)

Any suggestions how to accomplish this?

Comment: Two Explorer windows.

Comment: I would still have to navigate to the location in question in the second window. I am looking for a way to automate the navigation process, as I constantly have to switch between these 2 locations for MULTIPLE projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the Windows Explorer .... uh.. location bar(?) near the top (just under the edit, view, tools, etc), you can simply edit and type in the new location there.

Another possibility is simply to have a Shortcut on each folder pointing to the other side. So a shortcut on C:\Final\Projects\Project A that points to C:\Draft\Projects\Project A, and vice versa.

Comment: I am looking for a method that uses some sort of batch commands that are run via right click, since it would be very tedious creating individual shortcuts for every single project folder and is something I would like to avoid. Especially since the file paths will be similar for each "case", I figure some sort of wildcards or command line operations could be automated to accomplish this. Manually typing the address is not something I would consider, as it takes longer than navigating manually.